# U+011B ('ecaron') is not available in the font Helvetica, encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

Tags: java, pdfbox, boxable

Using PDFBox version 2.0.27.

Here is my code:

```
package com.mytest.tasks.createPDF;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AddingContent {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument()) {
            PDPage myPage = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage(myPage);
            try (PDPageContentStream cont = new PDPageContentStream(doc, myPage)) {
                cont.beginText();
                cont.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 12);
                cont.setLeading(14.5f);
                cont.newLineAtOffset(25, 700);
                String line1 = "schodiště západ";
                cont.showText(line1);
                cont.endText();
            }
            doc.save("D:\\Temp\\QRCode\\QR_PDF_PDFBOX_Output.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

But when it tries to set the values like "schodiště západ", it failed with the error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+011B ('ecaron') is not available in the font Helvetica, encoding: WinAnsiEncoding at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.encode(PDType1Font.java:428) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:333) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showTextInternal(PDPageContentStream.java:514) at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:476) at com.mytest.tasks.qrcode.AddingContent.main(AddingContent.java:27)`

Comment: Not sure what the question is! *Apparently* the Helvetica font does not support that character - your options: 1) use a different font; 2) change the character; 3) add the missing glyph to the font (not really)

Comment: Using 'WinAnsiEncoding' seems a bit last-century, though.  Is there some way to use Unicode?  Would that make any difference?

Comment: This is in the FAQ: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#i'm-getting-java.lang.illegalargumentexception%3A-...-is-not-available-in-this-font's-encoding%3A-winansiencoding

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as said in the error message: the target font for the PDF does not contain a glyph for the character named in the error message.

So choose another font for your PDF that contains glyphs for all characters you are intended to use in your text.

What is so difficult in understanding that error message?